# Redirecting to an Angular application with Token Bearer

Tags: angular, redirect, token, asp.net-authorization

One of our devs is working with ***KeyCloak*** to grab an Authorization ***Token*** before **redirecting** to our Angular application.

Is it possible to even READ that token on the front end when our angular app bootstraps? Or do we need to go straight to the server in order to read that token?

For example, I can use **Postman** or **reqbin**.com (with Chrome extension) to make the GET request to my app.

But in terms of reading that auth bearer token on the front end - can it be done?

**Sample GET request to login page:**

```js
    var url = "http://localhost:4200/#/login";

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url);

    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer MyTestToken123");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
       if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
          console.log(xhr.status);
          console.log(xhr.responseText);
       }};

    xhr.send();
```

and I do get the SUCCESS message below.

[image]

Naturally we could send it via Query Params, but that is not desirable.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: If the token is persisted on the client side using one of the browser's APIs then it can be read before redirection. If in the previous step it is not persisted then it is obvious that a backend request is needed

Comment: @onrails - your 2nd statement is correct in our scenario. Before our Angular app is even bootstrapped, Keycloak (used for SSO) is generating the token on behalf of the user. At this point Keycloak redirects to our Angular app with the token.